# Adding a field to the Solr Schema

Tags: php, solr, schema

I am looking to add a field to the Solr schema.

I'm aware that after adding a field to the `schema.xml`, I have to restart the Solr-instance and rebuild the index. However, does the `schema.xml` reside on the Solr server or should I change the `schema.xml` that I am exporting?

Also, does "rebuild the index" refer to exporting data to the Solr search server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

schema.xml does not usually reside within the Solr Server.
It resides in the SOLR.HOME pointed through environment settings (tomcat settings fine, solr web.xml or passed as a system property) to an external directory which holds the cores, configurations and the index files.

If exporting the data means re-feeding the same data to Solr, then it will reindex the data.

Answer (score 0):

Schema file resides in the conf folder of solr home that contains the configuration setting of your index. Yes you have to re-create the index, if your are using DIH then your have to run data-import command again to see the effect of your change.

Comment: I am using Solarium as a "bridge" between my PHP code and the Apache Solr search server.